# Why is custom user password not getting set and authenticated?

Tags: python, django

I thought it would be a breeze to swap the User model's username with its email. So I am using a `CustomUser`.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from .managers import UserManager

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

Since **`CustomUser` is inherited from `AbstractUser` model**, I thought I was done, but I guess I am still far from it.

Here's my django shell interaction:

```py
>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
>> User = get_user_model()
>> User.objects.create(email='dave@gmail.com', password='123')                                                                                                                                        
   <CustomUser: dave@gmail.com> 
>> User.objects.get(email='dave@gmail.com').password
   '123' # wutt? why is this plaintext?
>> User.objects.get(email='dave@gmail.com').set_password('abc')
>> User.objects.get(email='dave@gmail.com').password
   '123' # still same!
```

So functionally, this is completely useless. Since `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` for the users always returns `None`. What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve the minimal functionality that my `CustomUser` is only different from default django User model in that my `CustomUser` should use email as the username?

I have already checked out the SO hits:

[Django User password not getting hashed for custom users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226977/django-user-password-not-getting-hashed-for-custom-users)

[django custom user model password is not being hashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674373/django-custom-user-model-password-is-not-being-hashed)

EDIT: I'm using the following as my `UserManager`

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Comment: How do you register / create your users? Also `set_password` does not save the user so naturally `User.objects.get(email='dave@gmail.com').set_password('abc')` would not change anything. Try something like `user = User.objects.get(email='dave@gmail.com')` then `user.set_password('abc')` and then `user.save()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `User.objects.create(email='dave@gmail.com', password='123')` to create your user. `.create()` does not take into consideration that the password needs to be hashed (it is a normal method provided by all models). Instead use `.create_user()`:

```
User.objects.create_user(email='dave@gmail.com', password='123')
```

Also you try to set the users password by writing:

```
User.objects.get(email='dave@gmail.com').set_password('abc')
```

This does not work because `set_password` does not save anything to the database. You should do this instead:

```
user = User.objects.get(email='dave@gmail.com')
user.set_password('abc')
user.save()
```

Comment: Hmm not sure why I would get `create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'`

Comment: @DaveIdito did you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.CustomUser`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. This is the right answer. I was debugging, and turns out my `objects = UserMa...` line was commended. It all works now.